# Creating deep-safe bookmarks in Eve Online?

Tags: eve-online

It used to be possible to create 'deep-safe' bookmarks, that were farther than 10 AU outside a system. As of the Tyrannis patch, [that's no longer possible](http://www.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&bid=748). So what *is* possible, and how? Can you make a bookmark that's 9 AU out-system?

According to the link, you can no longer warp to distant objects (such as other systems), so there's no way to make a mid-warp bookmark at 9 AU. Is Microwarp Drive the only option for going long-range? Because that's a *long* way to run on MWD. :)

Update: according to [another blog post](http://www.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&bid=753), it sounds like CCP is not deleting existing deepsafes, just moving them inwards to the 20 AU limit. But it's not clear if we can still *make* deepsafes, even at 20 AU. Anyone know if they still *can* be made? And how?

Comment: I am adding a bounty to get some up-to-date tutorials on how to accomplish "deep-safe" spots (ones that are still allowed within range limitations) quickly.

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin. Unfortunately, I suspect the only answer is, "no, they can't be created". On the one hand, it would make sense. OTOH, if CCP really leaves alone bookmarks at the 20AU limit (as opposed to deleting them), then it seems to give an advantage to anyone who had *previously* created a distant bookmark. Old-timers would have them, but newcomers couldn't create them. :(

Comment: worth a shot :P

Answer (score 2):

[The Poseidon method](http://go-dl1.eve-files.com/media/1003/Poseidon-Manual.pdf) should still work, to my knowledge of the patch.  I will confess I haven't attempted it.  It is, however, my understanding that any ultra-deep-safe created by this method will be pushed into the acceptable boundaries on the next downtime so I wouldn't try stashing anything there.

Mid-warp bookmarking to create off-lane safes is a much safer and more reliable method.  There's no such thing as an unprobable safe spot anymore.

Comment: Interesting - so that's one way people *used to* make deepsafes, I never knew that. My only question is - whether CCP **removed** it. CCP stated that they were fixing the bugs/glitches that allowed people to make deepsafes in the first place, and this is certainly a glitch-based method :) (Someday I will get back into the game enough to test it myself).

Comment: It's a lag-based system.  The day CCP removes lag from the game, I will assume this has been fixed.  It's possible it's been eliminated, but this would be the only remaining way you could pull off a deep-safe.  It was my understanding that the fix was a constant re-sweeping of objects and deletion of bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played in a while, but it's something like warping in to the sun with something large as you should be bounced really far out.

To get to the centre of the sun, you used to be able to fly in to into, by just flying towards it. Eventually you'll go in to it. I recommend an interceptor.

Comment: How long is "in a while"? :) The links point out that CCP has *removed* the various methods that were being used to create deepsafes.

Comment: Rereading the blogs, it looks like they took it out, but another method I know is, get in an interceptor, put a overdrives, nanos and a mwd and fly for awhile

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the "just fly there" method in my post. But you *do* realize that an AU is about 150 *million* kilometers, right? :) Given that a maxed interceptor could do about 2.5 kilometers/second - that's roughly **two years** to cross 1 AU.

Comment: I thought they could go faster than that, obviously been gone too long, it's been a few years.

Comment: Remember, we're talking about two different drive types - there's the normal-space drive (whatever it's called), which is measured in meters per second. Then there's the *warp* drive, an entirely different system, which is measured in Astronomical Units per second. For both systems, yes, the interceptors are bats-out-of-hell. But there's a big difference in warping 9 AU/second, versus flying at 400 *meters* per second. :)

Comment: raybritton was referring as all those nano-interceptors, with their OMG-unlimited-ROFLMAO-speed. By the way, it's still possible to reach 8km/s speeds., which make it 5 months/AU.

Comment: **Only 5 months**? I'll get started immediately. :)

Comment: Even you were being serious, it wouldn't work, as you knocked back in to the system now. But I remember when it was possible to travel another system without warp in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really *need* deepsafes. In most systems, you are able to position yourself 15 AU away from any celestial. You won't be on a scan anywhere, and you should have time to logoffski in that spot before a combat-prober finds you (assuming they have no intel where you are; save that you're in system).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as to whether or not it's still possible to make them, though.

Comment: I think you underestimate the power of good probers.

Comment: yes, i realize that i have not answered the questions. i have simply provided a practical solution as an alternative to having deep safes, which i believe could possibly be useful information to OP

i don't underestimate them. no matter how good you are, even with perfect skills, if they don't have any way pinpoint your location, so they will have to scan the system. and unless your in something huge, you should have plenty of time to log.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create deep safes is bookmarking the acceleration gate of Incursions. Those mission sites usually appear well out of D-Scan range of other objects in a solar system.

Obviously this method requires you to wait until there is an Incursion in the system that you are interested in.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know if MWD is the only option for going long-range.  The other two questions I can answer however: yes, it is possible to still make deep-safes (see [here, look under 'random safe spots'](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Safe_spot#.27Deep.27_Safe_Spots)), yes you can make deep-safes up to 10AU out.

Comment: First, the link is possibly *older* than the patch that removed deepsafes - and in any case, has no information about *how* to make them, only describing what they are. Second, using MWD is **not an option** for making deepsafes - if you look at the other comment thread, it's explained that it would takes *months* (realtime) just to travel one AU.

Comment: The MWD comment was facetious, of course I'm aware of the other comment thread.  And are you saying that the instructions in the link I posted are not valid?  I will copy them here.

Comment: The best way to make this type of bookmark  is to open your solar system map, and then follow these steps:

   1. Warp from your current position to another celestial object in the system, and while still warping create a bookmark. Call this bookmark Spot 1.
   2. Locate a different celestial object, and be sure that it is not on the same vector that you just came from. Warp to this object, and again while still in warp create a bookmark. Call this bookmark Spot 2.
   3. Warp back to Spot 1.

Comment: 4. Warp to Spot 2, and again take a bookmark in the middle of this journey. Call this bookmark Spot 3.
   5. You are now the proud owner of a "Random" Safe Spot providing Spot 3 is not positioned on any of the lines between celestial objects in this system.

Comment: I'm sorry if these instructions are wrong.  I haven't played in a long time.

Comment: @Glen, not so much wrong, as unrelated to the Question. I'm not asking how to make *random* safespots, but deepsafes - locations 10-20 AU outside a system. CCP has **changed** various game abilities, and you can no longer warp to a location that is *outside* of your current star-system.

Comment: @Cyclops I just assumed that due to the change, the new "deepsafe" is a random spot at 9 AU.  As far as I can tell, that was part of your question, if it was still possible to make bookmarks at 9 AU.  I didn't realise you are only talking about spots 10-20 AU out!

Comment: Sigh... It's not the distance I'm talking about - it's the direction. Previously - you could go to a star-system, travel to the planet with the largest orbit (farthest from the sun), and then warp outwards, making a bookmark at some random distance outwards, for instance 40AU. CCP changed things so you could no longer warp like that, and *were* going to delete bookmarks past 20AU. Apparently they decided to move distant bookmarks *inwards* to 20AU. But it's no longer possible to make them (I *think*, that's why the question) - so only older players have them.

Comment: Or, to put it another way - your 9 AU bookmark is *inside* the orbit of some planet, and thereby inside the star system. If you can make a bookmark that is 9 AU *outside* the system, that would be what I was looking for - 9, 10, 20 doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh, well I guess that explains it.  And also why I wasn't any good at EO.  Thanks.